# Precise definition of limit on edge of function

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Suppose we are to follow the definition of limit of epsilon delta.

How can we define a limit at the end of it interval?

for example

$f(x)=\sqrt{x}, x\in[0,\infty)$

$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$

do we say that the limit does not exist at $x\to 0$? since the very existential of $\delta$ would be impossible as the function would not be defined at :

$0-\delta$

Comment: In this case, $$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x) = L \iff \left(\forall\varepsilon>0\ \exists\delta>0\, :\, 0<x<\delta\implies |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon\right). $$

Comment: In the full definition, you only test the $x$ in the domain that satisfy $|x-0|<δ$, thus there is no problem.

Comment: yes but what about the left hand limit?
From the Theorem of one side limit

"A function $f(x)$ has limit as $x$ approaches $c$ if and only if it has left-hand and right-hand limits there and these one sided limits are equal"

Comment: $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L \iff \lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)=L \land \lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)=L$

Did't meant to spam , but I cant add above statement in edit as it passed 5 min

Comment: @Amirul That definition is wrong in general; it's correct only if $f$ is defined in a neighbourhood containing $c$.

Answer (score 1):

For any function $f:D\subset\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ and $x_0\in\bar D$, $$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=L$$ means that for all $ε>0$ exists a $δ>0$ so that for all $x\in D$ whenever $|x-x_0|<δ$ then $|f(x)-L|< ε$.

This is the general definition that easily can be modified to higher dimensional spaces or general metric spaces.

One sided limits are a specialty of real functions, as with a higher dimensional domains there is no easily defined "side".